# Rating Individual PowerPoint Slides in Sharepoint PowerPoint Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, powerpoint

I have come across a strange thing with SharePoint 2010. I have created a PowerPoint slide library which works great. But the users want the ability to rate each slide like they do with documents in a document library.

I enable ratings for the library in general settings and the column shows up in default view but there are no stars. At first I thought I might have screwed something up in my custom master page but then I checked and the 5 star rating column works in a normal document library.

So I thought it might be permission based as this is a locked down section of the site, so I created a PPT library in an open section of the site and still no stars.

So then I went right back to an unbranded, SharePoint 2010 Foundation server, created a PPT library and still no stars. I am completely lost and don't know what to do next.

Is this a bug or is it disabled for some particular reason?

Thanks ...

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in our SharePoint 2010 farm and found the same problem.But one more thing i noticed.

- If you click on the Edit properties of the a slide, now you can see the ratings column here. this is sort of workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That is so bizarre. Unfortunately we are not enabling edit for most users so back to square 1. So as a new SharePoint user how would I get confirmation that this is a bug?